# Exception Type: NoReverseMatch - Django

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

after researching for hours I cannot get rid of this error, I hope someone can help me.

Models:

```
class Puja(models.Model):
    seller = models.OneToOneField(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video = models.FileField(blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField("Published: ",default=timezone.now())
    bidding_end = models.DateTimeField()
    starting_price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    #slug = models.SlugField(null=True) 

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    #def get_absolute_url(self):
    #   return reverse('bidding_list_detail', args=[str(self.id)])  
    #slug time
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('bidding_list_detail',args={'id': self.id})
```

Views:

```
class bidding_list(ListView):
    model = Puja
    template_name = 'bidding_templates/bidding_list.html'
    """return render(request= request,
      template_name='bidding_templates/bidding_list.html',
      context = {"Pujas": Puja.objects.all})"""

class bidding_list_detail(DetailView):
    model = Puja
    template_name = 'bidding_templates/bidding_list_detail.html'
```

urls:

```
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("bidding_list/", bidding_list.as_view(), name="bidding_list"),
    path('<int:pk>', bidding_list_detail.as_view(), name='bidding_list_detail'),
```

admin:

```
class PujaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('seller','title','video','photo','published_date','bidding_end','starting_price')

admin.site.register(Puja,PujaAdmin)
```

template 1:

```
{% extends 'header.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Pujas</h1>

{% for Puja in object_list %} <!--object_list-->

<ul>
  <li><a href="{{ Puja.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ Puja.title }} </a></li>
</ul>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

template 2:

```
{% extends 'header.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div>
  <h2>{{ object.title }}</h2>
  <p>{{ object.seller }}</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Note that, whenever I remove `<a href="{{ Puja.get_absolute_url }}">` from the first template, the objects "puja" in the model get properly displayed on the template, but I cannot access them. They normally exist on the admin panel, but not displayed on the website directly.

Thank you very much on advance and stay healthy.

edit 1: Here is the urls.py directly from the app created by django. To be more specific, I created after the project a new app called "main" in which I programmed all the project, including all the code on this question except the edit.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

#from django.config import settings
#from django.config.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),

    #path('', include('model.urls')),
    #path('', include('blog.urls')),
    #path('', include('photo.urls')),
    #path('', include('video.urls')),

] # +static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: there seems to be some problem in urls.py , do you have any other urls.py in which ,you are including this file?

Comment: I did edit the question, thank you @Neeraj

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is this line - return reverse('bidding_list_detail',args={'id': self.id}), you are passing id as a string but trying to match with int in url.Try following `return reverse ('bidding_list_detail',args=[self.id])`

Comment: Actually, the problem is that he is passing `id` as the argument, but the url is expecting an argument called `pk`

Comment: How would you solve it on my code ? Thank you @Shinratensei

Comment: in `get_absolute_url`: `return reverse('bidding_list_detail',args={'pk': self.id})`